# Why internal server error when adding IP restrictions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with an MVC project. I have had IP restriction added to my web.config file for a long time. Now suddenly I am getting the internal server error:

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

When I remove the IP restriction section:

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true" denyAction="NotFound">
   <add ipAddress="x.x.x.x" />    
</ipSecurity>
```

Then the project works. Any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, future me...to solve this go to applicationhost.config. At the top there is a section with the tag `<configSections>`. Under this section go to section group `<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">`. Under there, you will find ipSecurity. Set its overrideModeDefault to Allow.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration) has the details about it.